# XCode или CLion?

Tags: xcode, macos, ide, clion

Хочу начать писать на `C++` под `MacOS`. В `Windows` пользовался только `MSVS`. Если существенные различия в удобстве/возможностях между этими `IDE`?
Не пользовался обоими. `XCode` привлекает тем, что он нативный и дефолтный аля `Visual Studio`. `CLion`, тем что это `JetBrains` и я очень люблю `PhpStorm` / `PyCharm`.

Comment: CLion большему тебя научит + там есть внизу терминал можешь писать свой gcc и компилировать прям от туда.

Comment: а еще лучше Qt  для C++ самое то и отладчик удобный и справка по самому Qt ) И код можно воспроизводить где угодно)